# Ajax post doesn't work when passing variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

While reading other similar questions I've learned that to send a javascript value to PHP variable I need to use AJAX. That's what I've done so far:

```
function onCursorChanged(e, data) {
    $.post('familytree.php', {id: data.context.id});
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
    else {
        $id = $individualid;
    }
    ?>
}
```

The problem is that when I check if `id` is posted it always goes to else statement (`id` is always equal to `individualid`). However, when I change my code to this:

```
function onCursorChanged(e, data) {
        $.post('familytree.php', {id: data.context.id, 
                                      success: function (msg){ 
                                           alert('success') },
                                      error: function (err){ 
                                           alert(err.responseText)}
                                      });
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
        }
        else {
            $id = $individualid;
        }
        ?>
    }
```

EDIT: the code above is mixed incorrectly because of a lot of experimenting I've been doing. The original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onCursorChanged(e, data) {
    $.post('familytree.php', {id: data.context.id});
    }
    </script>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
                                }
            else {
                $id = $individualid;
            }
        $this->displayLeafEditForm ($_SESSION['username'], $id, $this->getParents($id));
```

Thanks to all the answers I realised that id is not set that's why I can't get the value in php. But I don'y understand why because data.context.id is the id of the item clicked and set after each click.

I get the message that says 'success'. Any idea why can't I get my variable posted?

Comment: are u sure {id: data.context.id} is setting id value. Check on web browser tool to see what value is getting sent.

Comment: is data.context.id set? what is familytree.php? is there function reading post array? why are you mixing php and jquery?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I did what you said and no it doesn't and that's weird, because data.context.id is the id of diagram's item that is clicked.

Comment: @M.Svrcek, data.context.id is the id of diagram's item that is clicked, it is set on each click, I would like to pass the id of clicked item to php. familytree.php is where I would like to post the value. I'm mixing php and jquery because I was trying to do many things to find out why I didn't get the value, that wasn't my original code and PHP will be used in another function when I manage to find out why I can't set the value.

Comment: I've rollbacked your inclusion of a solution in the question: please find it [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/af1d44bd-21e6-4eb8-b105-612fac9ceef9/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here is that you mixing PHP and JavaScript incorrectly.  You are expecting `$_POST['id']` to be set in the JavaScript before it goes to the client. But by the time the JavaScript reaches the client, the PHP processing is already complete.

This means that when the `$.post()` happens, the server has already decided whether `if (isset($_POST['id']))` is true. The server sends the output (the JavaScript) on to the client, and then no more PHP processing will happen.

Also, you are passing `id`, `success`, and `error` as data, which is almost certainly not what you want. You want this:

```
$.post('familytree.php',
    {id: data.context.id},
    success: function (msg){ 
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function (err){ 
        alert(err.responseText)
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I shouldn't mix them. I've been trying to do many things to understand why I can't get the value and that's what I ended up with. That isn't my original code and PHP will be used in another function when I manage to find out why I can't set the value. data.context.id is the id of each diagram's item that I'm trying to display. It is set when the item is clicked. Why it doesn't set id value then?

Comment: The problem isn't mixing them, per se; it's that you mix them incorrectly. It is impossible for the code you have used above to ever work; you are asking the JavaScript to send POST data and then use PHP within the same JavaScript to read that POST data. That will never work; by the time the JavaScript runs, the PHP code has been executed and will not change. In other words, the POST data is evaluated when the JavaScript loads, not when you do your `$.post()`.

Comment: I realise it but it hasn't worked before I mixed them this way. I've made a few changes to my questions and put my original code in it. Is this correct, can I mix jquery and php this way?

Comment: No, you can't. `data.context.id` is a JavaScript variable. `$_POST['id']` is a PHP variable. They aren't the same, and my comments above apply to all three versions of your code. The PHP is evaluated before the page reaches the user, so `$_POST['id']` will not be set when you do your `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What I can do then? What is the solution to my problem? Is there a way to do what I need to do?

Comment: You can just use `data.context.id` (in JavaScript) where you currently have PHP. There's no need for any PHP there, or even anything to do with the server response.

Comment: Actually, I can't use it only in Javascript because I need to make it work with the rest of my code, for example, delete a record from db when a button is clicked.

Comment: Then you need to use AJAX to communicate with your server. But you cannot use PHP and JavaScript interactively with each other in the way your current code does.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX `success` function cares whether the asynchronous call occurred without error. The fact that you even reached `if (isset(...))` (and didn't set any error code eg. with `header(...)`) means that the AJAX call succeeded.

If `isset` is returning false, you need to look closer at the information that your AJAX call is actually sending to the PHP. Try putting in `print_r($_POST)` to see what post values you're actually getting.

Comment: data.context.id is the id of diagram's item that is clicked, it is set on each click, I would like to pass the id of clicked item to php. I tried to check on web browser tool now and it says that id is undefined. Any idea why is that?